# COLLATE for Coredata created INDEX

Tags: iphone, core-data

**Short Question:**

Is there a way to tell CoreData to use COLLATE while creating INDEX?

**Detailed Explanation:**

I need to show list of Clients in case insensitive sorted list by name. The "name" field is marked for INDEXING in xCode. I am using the following sort descriptor:

```
sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

This results in the following query from CoreData. All good till now.

```
SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZNAME FROM ZCLIENT t0 WHERE  t0.Z_PK IN  (?, ?, ?)  ORDER BY t0.ZNAME COLLATE NSCollateLocaleSensitiveNoCase  LIMIT 20
```

But if I look at the INDEX created by CoreData, it does not use COLLATE while creating INDEX. This would mean that all case insensitive queries would be slow for large data set.

```
CREATE INDEX ZCLIENT_ZNAME_INDEX ON ZCLIENT (ZNAME)
```

Is there a way to create a COLLATE based INDEX? Is there a way to specify that in xCode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  If you'd like the ability to do so, please file [an enhancement request](http://bugreport.apple.com).  You get extra bonus points from the CoreData team if you can include a sample project showing how COLLATE would make things superbly and awesomely faster.

Comment: Strange!. Is it not the most elementary feature for any string based column? Why would they leave this out? And equally strange is that I did not find any other query on this feature. How everyone is coping without this? In memory sorting?